# How to change the offset of calldata value?

Tags: solidity, keccak, bytes, calldata, function-selector

Suppose I have a contract below:

```
contract Hack {

    Switch private target;

    constructor(address _target) {
        target = Switch(_target);
    }

    function test() external pure returns (bytes memory){

       // 'hashOfFunction' is calculated via generateData() function.
        bytes memory hashOfFunction = hex"20606e15b70f0894e0e83ae9593ae406a94abb5adcfcf0d169c6784f02198dc3";
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("flipSwitch(bytes)", hashOfFunction);
    
    }
    
    function generateData() external pure returns (bytes32){
        return keccak256("turnSwitchOff()"); 
    }



    function turnSwitchOff() public {
         // extra code....
    }

    function flipSwitch(bytes memory _data) public {
         // extra code....
    }


}
```

The calldata output obtained by calling the test function is :---

```
// OutPut from test 
    // 0x
    // 30c13ade - function signature of flipSwitch(bytes) function.
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 - Offset of 32 bytes
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 - Size of parameter turnSwitchOff() 32 bytes
    // 20606e15b70f0894e0e83ae9593ae406a94abb5adcfcf0d169c6784f02198dc3 - signature of turnSwitchOff()
```

From the Output we can see that Offset is 32 bytes, but if we want to change it to 64 bytes or 96 bytes is it possible to do that? I mean is it possible to only change the Offset and keep all the calldata output same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test() external pure returns (bytes memory){
    bytes memory hashOfFunction = hex"20606e15b70f0894e0e83ae9593ae406a94abb5adcfcf0d169c6784f02198dc3";
    bytes memory a = abi.encodeWithSignature("flipSwitch(bytes)", hashOfFunction);
    a[0x23] = 0x40;
    return a;
}
```

The calldata output:

```
0x30c13ade
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
20606e15b70f0894e0e83ae9593ae406a94abb5adcfcf0d169c6784f02198dc3
```

Comment: I think this the only way to achieve this, just want to confirm you are updating the 35th index of bytes array a. Right?

Comment: Yeah, and in this case.